# Determinant of a matrix consisting of sines

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

From page 166 of Li Jiong Sheng's *Linear Algebra* (ISBN:9787312022982),

$$\begin{vmatrix}
 \sin(\theta_1) & \sin(2\theta_1) & \cdots & \sin(n\theta_1) \\
 \sin(\theta_2) & \sin(2\theta_2) & \cdots & \sin(n\theta_2) \\
 \vdots         & \vdots          & \ddots & \vdots          \\
 \sin(\theta_n) & \sin(2\theta_n) & \cdots & \sin(n\theta_n) \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Using Matlab, I got a complex result, like a cyclic expansion of each term. I wonder how to get this cyclic result.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699301/339790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thank Rodrigo de Azevedo for providing the link for
the solution to a similar question.
Let $U_n(x)$ be the $n$-th degree Chebychev polynomial
of the **second** kind.

1. The leading term of $U_n(x)$ is $2^nx^n.$
2. $U_n(\cos\theta))\sin\theta=\sin(n+1)\theta.$
   Observe that row $k$ of the given matrix is
   $$\sin\theta_k(1, U_1(\cos\theta_k),\dots,U_{n-1}(\cos\theta_k))\tag1$$
   After applying suitable determinant-preserving column operations to the matrix, row $k$ becomes
   $$\sin\theta_k(1, 2x_k,\dots,2^{n-1}x^{n-1}_k),\tag2$$
   where $x_k=\cos\theta_k.$ If we remove suitable factors along rows and columns, we get a Vandermonde matrix. Thus, the original determinant equals
   $$2^{n(n-1)\over2}\sin\theta_1\cdots\sin\theta_n\prod_{1\le j\lt k\le n}(\cos\theta_k-\cos\theta_j)$$